# how to hand over a value to React Context Provider

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Iam trying to provide an Auth Token to my components via Context. It seems that an object is handed over to my child component, however neither the default value, nor the value I set in the Provider reaches the child. What am I doing wrong?

```
AuthTokenContext.js
import React from 'react'

const AuthTokenContext = React.createContext({token: 'asd'})

export const AuthTokenProvider = AuthTokenContext.Provider
export const AuthTokenConsumer = AuthTokenContext.Consumer

export default AuthTokenContext

UrlManager.js
import { AuthTokenProvider } from './AuthTokenContext.js'
class UrlManager extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)}

  render(){
    return(
      <AuthTokenProvider value={{token: 'test'}}>
        <MainPage />
      </AuthTokenProvider>
    )
  }
}

MainPage.js
import AuthTokenContext from './AuthTokenContext'
class MainPage extends React.Component{
  static contexType = AuthTokenContext
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const temp = this.context
    console.log(temp) //console output: {}
  }
```

Comment: Its just a typo. You have contexType instead of `contextType`. `static contextType = AuthTokenContext`

Comment: i dont believe this, I read it like a million times. Thanks!

Comment: No issues. It happens a lot